# Google Maps API, How to Get Services (text Search) in Whole City or the whole portion of map that is in view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

When I did a Text Search with

```
var request = {
    location: placeobject,
    radius: 50000,
    query: placetypes
//  types: placetypes
};
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
```

But All I Get is the chunk of services clogged near the location i send, but how to specify text search to mark all such services in the whole city or a wider region to be searched.

Screenshot of what i get is [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get "the whole city".

[textSearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) and [nearBySearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) are limiited to 60 results total, in [groups of 20](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_responses).

> By default, each Place search returns up to 20 establishment results per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages.

[radarSearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests) will return up to 200 results, but with less detail.

> A Places Radar Search is initiated with a call to the PlacesService's radarSearch() method, which will return an array of up to 200 PlaceResult objects. PlaceResult objects returned by radarSearch() will only include the geometry.location and reference properties.