# How to get more than 64 result from google map api

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps-api-3

How to get more than 64 result using google map api

```
var restName="Pizza hut";
function initialize() {
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(19.125362 , 72.866467);//var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 0
  });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 50000,
    types: ['restaurant'],
    input: [restName]


  };

  placesList = document.getElementById('places');

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
```

But it gives me only 64 result using pagination.
how to get all country result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API, How to Get Services (text Search) in Whole City or the whole portion of map that is in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683098/google-maps-api-how-to-get-services-text-search-in-whole-city-or-the-whole-po)

Answer (score 0):

What does the returned result say after 64 results?
I guess that google map API restricts you from calling there API that often
without using their API for business.